# Как в TypeScript, указать глобальную переменную из js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, frontend

TypeScript собираю webpack через ts-loader. Есть отдельный, не типизированный js файл myNewLib.js, в котором объявляется глобальная переменная myLib. (Переводить его на TypeScript сейчас не могу)

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в TypeScript, показать, что есть глобальная переменная myLib, и указать для неё тип?**

*Сейчас когда в *.ts пишу глобальную переменную myLib, то получаю ошибку ts, что нету такой переменной....*

Хотелось бы где нибудь в одном месте, глобально объявить тип для переменной myLib, и объявить, что она глобальная, и дальше её уже во всех файлах использовать как глобальную, можно ли это как то сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как указано в [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables), для этого объявления глобальной переменной нужно воспользоваться `declare var`, также допустимы `let` и `const`

```
/** The number of widgets present */
declare var foo: number;
```

Comment: Я видел, но у меня это почему то не работает. Возможно из за того, что это модули.  Пишу в одном файле declare var foo: number;, а в другом, foo=5 и получаю ошибку TS2304: Cannot find name 'foo'.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt1, читай [справку о структуре](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html)

Comment: Я прочитал, что можно сделать global.d.ts, но не понимаю, где этот файл разместить, и где подключить, что бы он работал?

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt1, можно в той же папке где и код.

Comment: Я добавил в той же директории где и находится файл в котором используется переменная, но это не помогло, и в родительскую папку пытался добавлять, но тоже не помогает....

Comment: Хотя нет, извиняюсь, сработало. В той же папке сработало. Но у меня много  папок, получается нужно во всех. Можно ли как то сделать что бы в корневой?

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt1, по идее и так должно работать. попробуй просто по использовать его в других файлах

Comment: Видимо я что то делаю не так, когда ложу в корневую, у меня и webpack выдаёт ошибки, и phpStorm, подчёркивает, её как не существующую в ts.